# TypeScript Unexpected token, A constructor, method, accessor or property was expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Just trying to write a function within a class using typescript.

```
class Test 
{
    function add(x: number, y: number): number {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

This results in the following error:

> TypeScript Unexpected token, A constructor, method, accessor or
>   property was expected.

I copied the example from: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

Am I missing something? I'm confused!

Comment: You copied an example from the section on functions into the middle of a class. Check out any documentation, tutorial or blog post on JS/TS classes to see how to define methods.

Comment: This `function` key word is wrong. You can not use it inside a class to define a method. Just remove it and this code will be fine.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `function` keyword in a Typescript class definition. Try this instead:

```
class Test { 
    add(x: number, y: number): number {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

TypeScript does not allow `function` declarations as class members; it has a slightly different syntax for that...

```
class Test 
{
    // This will bind the add method to Test.prototype
    add(x: number, y: number): number 
    {
        return x + y;
    }

    // This will create a closure based method within the Test class
    add2 = (x: number, y: number) => {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "closure-based method" mean?

Comment: @torazaburo when a method is bound to the prototype, only one instance of that method is ever created, and is executed contextually by the caller instance. When using closures, the method is created per-instance and enclosed within the constructor function. Closure based methods have the advantage of being able to access private instance members outside the scope of their execution, which is not possible with prototype bound methods, however prototype bound methods tend to perform better.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference for the terminology "closure-based method"?

Comment: @torazaburo https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: I know what closures are. I don't know the term "closure-based method". it's not standard, and possibly confusing. If you want to refer to methods on instances, then just say "methods on instances". I'm also wondering about your assertion that methods on prototypes perform better. Why would that be, and in what sense?

Comment: @torazaburo a closure based method (whilst being slightly non standard) is a method implemented using closures, which are fairly standard and commonplace in JS. "Methods on instances" is much less indicative of what's going on here; certainly not an expression I'd use when I meant a closure. As for the performance argument, after a little further investigation, it would appear somewhat historical information, as modern browsers have been able to improve the performance of closures to the same, if not better level as prototype bound members

Comment: Hardly think that use of terminology deserved a downvote when the rest of the answer addressed the question perfectly.

Comment: @MikeChamberlain thank you. I thought it was needlessly nitpicky

Answer (score 1):

The same error is also thrown when you try to access a property outside a life-cycle hook. You need to access them in a life-cycle hook or constructor like:

```
class Test {

  x: number;
  y: number;

  add(x: number, y: number): number {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    return this.x + this.y;
  }
}

...
export class Component implements OnInit {

  test: Test = new Test();
  test.x = 0; // NOK, will throw: Unexpected token, A constructor... error

  constructor() { 
    test.x = 0; // OK
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    test.x = 0; // OK
  }
}
```