# Fundamental issue with Typescript - "[ts] Unexpected token. A contruction, method..."

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I keep getting weird errors when writing a simple anonymous function declarations. 
I tried to search for a solution but I can't find one.

[image: Simple Problem]

It also happens when i write this:

```
functionOne();

var functionOne = function() {
  console.log("Hello!");
};
```

or this

```
(()=> {
  //something
})
```

Comment: Try updating your `tsconfig.json` in order to target to the right version of javascript, like `"target": "ES5",`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript Unexpected token, A constructor, method, accessor or property was expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070702/typescript-unexpected-token-a-constructor-method-accessor-or-property-was-exp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `let` or `const` in your case, inside class in Angular you can simply write `myVar = "Value"` or `public myVar = "Value"` (if you want to make your variable public) or `private myVar = "Value"` (if you want to make your variable private)

Answer (score 2):

I think that `let` keyword is not needed because you declare a property of the class.

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following

```
myAdd(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}
```

or you can do this

```
function(x, y) {
   return x + y;
}
```

The keywords `let` and `var` are for variables.