# How to use the Data object in VueJS when using Decorators? "Expected 'this' to be used by class method 'data'."

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, decorator

Error > Expected 'this' to be used by class method 'data'.

I did find this, and thought I had it correct below:
[TypeScript Unexpected token, A constructor, method, accessor or property was expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070702/typescript-unexpected-token-a-constructor-method-accessor-or-property-was-exp)

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import { MOON_HOLDINGS_LINK, TWITTER_LINK } from '@/constants/links'

@Component
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  @Prop() private title!: string

  data(): any {
    return {
      moonLink: MOON_HOLDINGS_LINK,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thats just from the linter. you can override that in your base config. If you haven't already you can also use the [eslint-plugin-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue) to help with usage of directives and style guide :)

Comment: Thanks @JohnRuddell! Yeah static also fixed the issue, but also yeah I didn't need these variables in the data() method.

Comment: Oh hey Leon! didn't realize that was you :D

Comment: @JohnRuddell sup man hehe, how's Whoat these days? btw build this in React/Typescript lmk what you think: https://moon.holdings

Comment: Haha I moved from that place a long time ago! We should catch up sometime :) I'll check it out this evening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's due to the [class-methods-use-this](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/class-methods-use-this) rule of ESLint.

But `data()` shouldn't need to use `this` (only in very rare situations).

So you probably should suppress the warning for that specific method, as I believe `data()` meets the scenario described by [ESLint as a possible exception to that rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/class-methods-use-this#exceptions):

> For example, you might have a spec from an external library that requires you to overwrite a method as a regular function (and not as a static method) and does not use `this` inside the function body.

So you would use:

```ts
/*eslint class-methods-use-this: ["error", { "exceptMethods": ["data"] }] */
```

Example:

```ts
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import { MOON_HOLDINGS_LINK, TWITTER_LINK } from '@/constants/links'

@Component
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  @Prop() private title!: string

  /*eslint class-methods-use-this: ["error", { "exceptMethods": ["data"] }] */
  data(): any {
    return {
      moonLink: MOON_HOLDINGS_LINK,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It would be annoying to write out the ignore comment for every Vue class. Probably better to stuff that override in a `.eslintrc` or something