# How can I replace an arrow function defined into map() operator with an externalized function?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am not yet into Angular and TypeScript and I have the following doubt about how to refactor my code.

Into my TypeScript component class code I have something like this:

```
this.eventService.getEvents().subscribe(eventsSnaps => {
  this.events = eventsSnaps.map(currentEventSnap => {
    //console.log("DOCUMENT ID: ", currentCourseSnap.payload.doc.id);
    //console.log("DATA: ", currentCourseSnap.payload.doc.data());
    var currentEvent = {
      id: currentEventSnap.payload.doc.id,
      ...currentEventSnap.payload.doc.data()
    };

    var date = currentEventSnap.payload.doc.data().start.toDate()
    var hour = date.getHours();

    var startDateAsString = this.fromDateToString(date);

    console.log("startDateAsString: ", startDateAsString);
    console.log("hour: ", hour);

    currentEvent.start = startDateAsString;

    if(hour === 7) {
      currentEvent['backgroundColor'] = 'red';
    }
    else if(hour === 15) {
      currentEvent['backgroundColor'] = 'green';
    }
    else if(hour === 23) {
      currentEvent['backgroundColor'] = 'black';
    }

    return currentEvent;     
  });
  console.log("EVENTS FROM SNAPS: ", this.events);
});
```

This code works fine and basically it is subscribing an **Observable** containing data retrieved from Firebase Firestore database and performing some logic on these retrieved data.

My problem is that in my code I need to do multiple subscription (to different service method) that performs the exact same logic defined into the **map()** arrow function.

My idea is to externalize all this logic into a single funcion that will be passed to all the map() function in my code that need to implement this behavior. Could be a good idea?

In casi it is not so bad as idea how can I define a function encapsulating this logic and use it as replacement of my arrow function defined into the previous **map()**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats pretty easy and a nice question. You can use the rxjs [map](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) operator for this task:

```
const eventSnaps$ = this.eventService.getEvents().pipe(
  map(events => events.map(currentEventSnap => {
    //console.log("DOCUMENT ID: ", currentCourseSnap.payload.doc.id);
    //console.log("DATA: ", currentCourseSnap.payload.doc.data());
    var currentEvent = {
      id: currentEventSnap.payload.doc.id,
      ...currentEventSnap.payload.doc.data()
    };

    var date = currentEventSnap.payload.doc.data().start.toDate()
    var hour = date.getHours();

    var startDateAsString = this.fromDateToString(date);

    console.log("startDateAsString: ", startDateAsString);
    console.log("hour: ", hour);

    currentEvent.start = startDateAsString;

    if(hour === 7) {
      currentEvent['backgroundColor'] = 'red';
    }
    else if(hour === 15) {
      currentEvent['backgroundColor'] = 'green';
    }
    else if(hour === 23) {
      currentEvent['backgroundColor'] = 'black';
    }

    return currentEvent;     
  })
)

eventSnaps$.subscribe(eventsSnaps => {
  this.events = eventsSnaps;
  console.log("EVENTS FROM SNAPS: ", this.events);
});
```

If you go one step ahead you could refactor your code even more and move the rxjs mapping into a separate function:

```
function mapEventsToEventsSnaps(events) => events.map(currentEventSnap => {
    //console.log("DOCUMENT ID: ", currentCourseSnap.payload.doc.id);
    //console.log("DATA: ", currentCourseSnap.payload.doc.data());
    var currentEvent = {
      id: currentEventSnap.payload.doc.id,
      ...currentEventSnap.payload.doc.data()
    };

    var date = currentEventSnap.payload.doc.data().start.toDate()
    var hour = date.getHours();

    var startDateAsString = this.fromDateToString(date);

    console.log("startDateAsString: ", startDateAsString);
    console.log("hour: ", hour);

    currentEvent.start = startDateAsString;

    if(hour === 7) {
      currentEvent['backgroundColor'] = 'red';
    }
    else if(hour === 15) {
      currentEvent['backgroundColor'] = 'green';
    }
    else if(hour === 23) {
      currentEvent['backgroundColor'] = 'black';
    }

    return currentEvent;     
  });
```

Then you can re-use the function in your pipe. This makes your pipe more readable, separates your code and makes the function itself testable:

```
const eventsSnaps$ = this.eventService.getEvents().pipe(
  map(events => mapEventsToEventsSnaps(events))
);
```

Comment: Ok, but where have I to define this function? (I mean the function mapEventsToEventsSnaps(events) ). If I put it as function of my TypeScript class the IDE give me the following error: "Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070702/typescript-unexpected-token-a-constructor-method-accessor-or-property-was-exp

Comment: If you want to add your function in a class you can not use the function keyword. If you want to safe this function in a pure .ts file, epxort it there and import it anywhere you can use the function keyword.